# Extending absolute continuity by proving a necessary and sufficient condition.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Problem:** Show that $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[a, b]$ iff for each $\epsilon>0,$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for every countable disjoint collection $\left\{\left(a_{k}, b_{k}\right)\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of open intervals in $(a, b),$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|f\left(b_{k}\right)-f\left(a_{k}\right)\right|<\epsilon \text { if } \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[b_{k}-a_{k}\right]<\delta
$$
**Proof:** First, assume that $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[a, b] .$ Let $\epsilon>0$ be since $f$ is absolutely continuous, there is a $\delta$ such that if
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|f\left(b_{k}\right)-f\left(a_{k}\right)\right|<\epsilon \text { if } \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[b_{k}-a_{k}\right]<\delta
$$
We require that for every countable disjoint collection $\left\{\left(a_{k}, b_{k}\right)\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of open intervals in $(a, b),$ there exists a $\delta^{*}$ such that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|f\left(b_{k}\right)-f\left(a_{k}\right)\right|=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|f\left(b_{k}\right)-f\left(a_{k}\right)\right|+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left|f\left(b_{k}\right)-f\left(a_{k}\right)\right|<\epsilon
$$
if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[b_{k}-a_{k}\right]<\delta^{*}$

$\ldots$

Now assume that for every $\epsilon>0,$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for every countable disjoint collection $\left\{\left(a_{k}, b_{k}\right)\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of open intervals in $(a, b),$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|f\left(b_{k}\right)-f\left(a_{k}\right)\right|<\epsilon \text { if } \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[b_{k}-a_{k}\right]<\delta
$$
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|f\left(b_{k}\right)-f\left(a_{k}\right)\right|<\epsilon \text { if } \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[b_{k}-a_{k}\right]<\delta
$$
Then for every finite disjoint collection $\left\{\left(a_{k}, b_{k}\right)\right\}_{k=1}^{n}$ of open intervals in $(a, b)$, if
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[b_{k}-a_{k}\right]<\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[b_{k}-a_{k}\right]+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left[b_{k}-a_{k}\right]=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left[b_{k}-a_{k}\right]<\delta
$$
then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|f\left(b_{k}\right)-f\left(a_{k}\right)\right|<\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|f\left(b_{k}\right)-f\left(a_{k}\right)\right|+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left|f\left(b_{k}\right)-f\left(a_{k}\right)\right|=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|f\left(b_{k}\right)-f\left(a_{k}\right)\right|< \epsilon
$$
Hence $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[a, b]$.

I believe I successfully demonstrated the sufficient condition, which is below the elipses The problem is that I'm not sure how to choose $\delta^*$ in the first half of the proof to make the desired quantity less than epsilon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $\delta>0$ such that if $ \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n |b_k-a_k| < \delta$, then $$\sum_{k=1}^n |f(b_k)-f(a_k)| < \frac{1}{2}\epsilon$$

Now suppose $ \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty |b_k-a_k| < \delta$.

Then, we have $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n |b_k-a_k| < \delta$ for all $n$,
and hence $$\sum_{k=
1}^n |f(b_k)-f(a_k)| < \frac{1}{2}\epsilon  \quad \text{for all } n$$

That is, $\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$ is an upper bound for $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n |f(b_k)-f(a_k)|$ for all $n$.

Hence we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |f(b_k)-f(a_k)| \le \frac{1}{2}\epsilon < \epsilon$$

Comment: I'm not quite seeing how just because $\epsilon/2$ is an upper bound for the finite series for all $n$, it becomes an upper bound for the infinite series. Could you expound on that?

Comment: Sure; if $x_n$ is an increasing sequence, and $x_n < L$ for all $n$, then you must have $\lim_n x_n \le L$. In this case, the increasing sequence is the $\sum_n|f(b_n)-f(a_n)|$ and the upper bound is $\frac{1}{2} \epsilon$.